# How to increment or loop through the folders in a specific directory

Tags: c#, wpf, directory

I would like to implement a method to delete folders in a directory that no longer exist in my program. So far I have created an array of `strings` that will contain the folder's names that need to exist in the directory. After doing that, I would like to use a loop to compare each folder to the array -- if it does not find a match, it should be deleted.

I know how to delete a directory with no problem, however **I do not know how to loop through the existing folders in a directory location. How do I do this?**

I am sorry for the lack of a "what I have tried" section. As I stated above, I am familiar with other directory operations, but have not found a good explanation for this one. I will be happy to clarify my question if need be.

This is all I have found on this question : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

Comment: The link you've provided offers a pretty concrete explanation of how to do exactly what you want. Is there a particular part of the article that doesn't make sense, or is tripping you up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] folderlist;    
folderlist = Directory.GetDirectories("YourStartingDirectory");
foreach (string FolderName in folderlist)
{
      string rfoldername = Path.GetFileName(FolderName);
}
```

This will loop through all the directories of a given directory, if you need directory of a directory you will need to perform a repeat of this function giving a different starting directory i hope this helps

Comment: This is the best answer to the question because it provides me with the ability to get the individual sub directory paths and perform operations with them. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you've attempted to do, but you could do something like this:

```
string[] root = Directory.GetDirectories(
     RootDirectory, @"*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

string[] secondary = Directory.GetDirectories(
    SecondaryDirectory, @"*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

for(int r = 0; r < root.Length; r++)
    for(int s; s < secondary.Length; s++)
         if(root[r] != secondary[s])
              Directory.Delete(r, true);
```

This should iterate through the array's, then compare the two.  Then perform the desired task your looking for.